# iPhone14pro device, proximityMonitoringEnabled=YES, not lock screen when near the top of screen

Tags: ios, iphone

My code is like this:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setProximityMonitoringEnabled:YES];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(proximityStateDidChange:) name:UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

- (void)proximityStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)note
{
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].proximityState) {
        NSLog(@"有物品靠近");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"有物品离开");
    }
}
```

I tried putting my hand on the top of iphone14pro, my running code receive UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification and proximityState is YES, however, the problem is lock or blank screen did not happen. By the way, it works on devices priority to the iphone14pro.